# How to create a schema-bound function that counts nodes in an xml and then be able to persist this result in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have an xml column and I want to persist a node count in it in an adjacent column.

For example, in an xml given below, I have 3 nodes `a` and so I want to output it.

The problem that I have, however, is that I can't manage to create a generic schema-bound function that would take @xml and @nodeName so as to return the count of a specified node.

```
create function dbo.fnXmlCount_a (@xml xml) 
returns int with schemabinding
as begin
return (@xml.value('count(//a)', 'int'))
end

declare @xml xml;
set @xml = '
<r>
 <a></a>
 <b></b>
 <a></a>
 <c>
  <a></a> 
 </c>
</r>'

select dbo.fnXmlCount_a(@xml) aCount
```

Result of the last operation is:

```
aCount
3
```

And then I create a column on that table that has this xml field like so:

```
alter table [XmlTable] add column [aCount] as (dbo.fnXmlCount_a([xml])) persisted
```

But what I really would like to do is this:

```
alter table [XmlTable] add column [aCount] as (dbo.fnXmlNodeCount([xml], 'a')) persisted
```

Thanks!

**Update:**

We all know that `//` is really slow, so it would be great if you could figure out how to pass this path to search in in another variable; by default, this searching path would be `//`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
create function dbo.fnXmlCount (@xml xml, @name nvarchar(max))  
returns int with schemabinding 
as begin 
declare @count int
select @count = count(*)
from @xml.nodes('//*') as t(c)
where t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') = @name
return @count
end
```

Comment: This approach took 46 seconds to count nodes in my table while my initial hard-coded approach took about 6 seconds to complete. But it definitely works! :) But the performance is terrible, I'm going to play with it to see if I can improve performance.

Comment: Yeah, it will be a lot slower

Comment: An XML index might help.  The speed issue is probably not from using `//`, it's from using both `nodes` and then `value` over every resulting node.

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw, believe it or not but with the proper path specified it takes 11 seconds to complete

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a little better solution but the approach is similar to that of Daniel Renshaw.

```
create function [dbo].[fnXmlCount] (@xml xml, @nodeName nvarchar(max))  
returns int with schemabinding 
as begin 
return @xml.value('count(//*[local-name() = sql:variable("@nodeName")])', 'int')
end
```

However, there's still no solution as to how to pass the path to nodes being counted.

And it takes about 20 seconds to count nodes on my xml table.